# Try to pop up to a destination before navigating (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am trying to do something like this

```
private fun tryPopUpTo(route: String, navigate: () -> Unit) {
    val done = navController.popBackStack(route = route, inclusive = false)
    if (!done) {
        navigate()
    }
}
```

It doesn't work for routes with arguments. How can I solve this?
The idea is if I am navigating and the destination is on the back stack I just pop to it!

Comment: I don't know if Compose does things differently, but can you use an *action* to navigate, and set up the backstack with the `popUpTo` attribute? https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop

Answer (score 0):

The internal matching logic must consider the arguments as a part of the route and it can be fair since arguments are meant to reflect physical state changes in your UI, so they're practically different renders altogether. Hence, if you want to implement this logic, you'll likely need to hack it together. Create a custom navigation method that along with navigating off to the desired destination keeps a track of all the incoming navigation commands. The list could be saved to your viewModel which will preserve it for the duration of your app's life.

Comment: It kind of makes sense but not sure if I understand how to do it.